Can you determine if a matrix can be made symmetric in poly time?
Is there an efficient way to tell if a square binary matrix can be made symmetric by reordering its rows and columns?
I can't see how graph isomorphism can be reduced to this problem so maybe there is a polynomial time algorithm?
Motivation
I would like to determine if there is a member of the equivalence class that is the adjacency matrix of an undirected graph.
Failed attempt
We can make a bipartite graph from any binary matrix by making a set of nodes for the rows and a set of nodes for the columns and connecting a row node i to a column node j iff there is a 1 at (i, j) in the matrix. We would then need some way of solving the problem using the bipartite graph.

Can you share anything about the motivation or application or context in which you encountered this problem?

I suppose we are talking about a boolean matrix?

@Gribouillis Yes. I have added that.

If it can be made symmetric, it can be made symmetric by reordering only the rows.

(Not a computer scientist here) but here is an approach to eliminate many matrices. Starting with the bipartite graph $G$ that you described, let us define by induction a sequence of more and more refined partitions of the set of vertices $V(G)$, so that
\begin{equation}
\forall p\in {\mathbb N},\ \forall u\in V(G), u\in K_p(u)\subset V(G)
\end{equation}
We start with $\forall u\in V(G),\ K_0(u) = V(G)$. Let us define the multiset
\begin{equation}
M_p(u) = [K_p(v),\ v\in N(u)]
\end{equation}
where $N(u)$ is the open neighborhood of the vertex $u$ and
\begin{equation}
K_{p+1}(u) = \{v\in K_p(u): M_p(u) = M_p(v)\}
\end{equation}
By induction on $p$ we have $v\in K_p(u)\Leftrightarrow K_p(u) = K_p(v)$. If at any level a class $K_p(.)$ does not contain the same number of rows and columns, then the matrix cannot be made symmetric.
When all the classes stabilize, i.e when $\forall u\in V(G)\ K_{p+1}(u) = K_p(u)$, we can try to make the matrix symmetric by mapping the columns in a class to the rows of the same class. Only these rows can be mapped to these columns. This does not solve the problem completely but it gives a filter to eliminate many matrices. Also this filter is polynomial because before the classes stabilize, the number of classes increases at least by 1 at each step, and the number of classes in a partition is bounded by the number of vertices of the graph.
I created a toy implementation in Python, which actually found a valid permutation for the first 5x5 matrix that I tried: the following matrix can be made symmetric by rewriting its columns in the order $(4, 2, 1, 3, 5)$
\begin{equation}
\begin{pmatrix}
        1& 1& 0& 1& 1\cr
        0& 1& 0& 1& 0\cr
        0& 0& 1& 1& 0\cr
        1& 0& 1& 0& 1\cr
        0& 0& 1& 1& 1
\end{pmatrix}
\end{equation}
Edit: I discovered that this algorithm is essentially the same as the 1-dimensional Weisfeiler-Leman graph isomorphism test.
